# ng-click, ng-change not working in angular material datetimepicker

Tags: datetimepicker, angular-material

Hi all I'm using http://logbon72.github.io/angular-material-datetimepicker/ for angular material datetimepicker, It looks cool and great but problem is I can't able to perform ng-click and ng-change for validation purpose.
Can anyone help me.

Comment: Could you create a Plunker, or other. example?

Comment: @camden_kid can you go through above link.

Comment: The above link is just examples. Could you show me how you are using it?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2ePb5nf8vH71iH5byP7q?p=preview  @camden_kid , include ng-change and ng-click event for date time picker.

Comment: It looks like `ng-change` and `ng-click` are not available for these directives.   The closet I can achieve to `ng-change` is using `$scope.$watch` - http://plnkr.co/edit/bOg1gBbSm9rt6upQE0lB?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your help, $watch method is working. @camden_kid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `ng-change` and `ng-click` are not available for these directives. The way to achieve the equivalent of `ng-change` is to use `$scope.$watch` - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bOg1gBbSm9rt6upQE0lB?p=preview)

JS

```
$scope.$watch("vm.employee.dateOfBirth", function (newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
});
```